How can I flash an eMMC with an .img Linux file?
I have an STM32MP1 that are connected to an eMMC (Embedded Multi Media Card). My goal is to flash the eMMC with a Linux .img, built from Buildroot. The eMMC has the same pin configuration as a regular SD-card, which is very important to understand that eMMC and SD-card speaking the same protocol over the same communication bus.
But using .img file with STM32CubeProgrammer is not going to work, because STM32CubeProgrammer wants .tvs files instead of .img files.
So there must be another way I can flash the eMMC, though the STM32MP1 processor, via the USB OTG?
I mean. How else should you use .img files?

"... very important to understand that eMMC and SD-card speaking the same protocol over the same communication bus."  Actually that is incorrect. Despite similar physical interfaces and typically a shared controller, eMMC has a JEDEC specification, whereas SD card is spec'd by the SD card Association. Since they both present a block interface to the user, Linux has a top-level driver that combines the two. But the driver has to differentiate between eMMC versus SD card because of this incompatibility.  See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.10/source/drivers/mmc/core/core.c#L2092

Try balena etcher to copy your image on the sd card.
After successful eMMC/SD card writing, remove the sd card, put it in board and power the board.
